# distance between rows in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

if you have a UITableView filled with for example 3 rows.
like this,

```
------
------
------
```

how can i make this?

```
------

------

------
```

how can i change the distance between rows in a UITableView.

```
---- =  a  full row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {return 20;}
```

Implement this function in your m.-File. The value which is returned by this function consist of the height of the rows (px).

Comment: No.. heightForRowAtIndexPath makes a row larger with his Height.. i dont mean that. i mean the distance between 2 rows not the height of the row it self

Comment: ok, but then your example sketch is not so clear. there is a default border between two rows and i guess you cannot change this attribute. i never saw this. but you could create an empty ghost row, if i understand you right?

Comment: Yes sorry my bad it wasnt that clear, hmmmm ill check how the outcome will be with a ghost row and changing the attributes of the border

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here.  If you simply want extra space between your rows, you can take off the border of the cell and create a custom cell with extra white space and/or extra lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rowHeight property of the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Set the row height in your UITableView - make sure it's longer than the height of your cell.

That extra row height will render as height padding.

Comment: That seems like the best solution to me - I've used UITableView pretty extensively and as far as I know there isn't any in-built support for 'padding between cells'. If you really wanted you could probably do some subclassing / overriding to achieve it yourself but just setting the row height and keeping a certain amount on the top and bottom 'empty' will achieve the desired effect